# Hydration error in next.js - unmatched text, throwOnHydrationMismatch, updateHostRoot

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am facing this issue on a particular event page that has a route `event/[id]`. Apparently, my teammate who developed the code is not facing any problems. However, I face this issue whenever I reload the page. If I go to the page through normal flow i.e. `url/eventList` -> click on event card -> `url/event/[id]` then everything works fine. But as soon as I reload the page, I face hydration errors.

npm version: 8.19.3
node version: 16.17.0

Errors:

```
1. Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.
2. Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
3. Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
```

`/events/[id]` page;:

```
import Event from '../../../Components/Event/Event';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import classes from './event.module.css';

const EventDetails = (props) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const {
    query: { tid },
  } = router;

  return (
    <section style={{ minHeight: '91vh' }} className={classes.background}>
      <Event eventDetails={props.eventDetails} teamId={tid} />
    </section>
  );
};

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const events = await fetch(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_API + 'events/'
  ).then((res) => res.json());

  return {
    fallback: false,
    paths: events.map((event) => {
      const eventId = event.id;
      return {
        params: {
          id: eventId,
        },
      };
    }),
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const eventId = context.params.id;
  const res = await fetch(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_API + 'events/' + eventId
  );
  if (!res || res.status != 200) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }
  const eventDetails = await res.json();
  return {
    props: {
      eventDetails: eventDetails,
    },
    revalidate: 100,
  };
}

export default EventDetails;
```

package.json :-

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run prettify && next dev",
    "build": "npm run prettify && next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "npm run prettify && next lint",
    "prettify": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js, jsx}\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "11.10.4",
    "@emotion/server": "11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.10.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.10.6",
    "@mui/material": "5.10.6",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.3",
    "cryptr": "^6.0.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.5",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "mui-file-dropzone": "^4.0.2",
    "next": "12.2.5",
    "next-auth": "^4.12.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-share": "^4.4.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.0.8",
    "swr": "^1.3.0",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.5.0",
    "prettier": "2.7.1"
  }
}
```

I have tried modifying getStaticPaths and getStaticProps but this issue still persists.

Comment: What do you have in the `Event` component?

Comment: Nothing you have in `EventDetails` would trigger such error. The issue is most likely downstream in `Event` (or in one of its children). Can you show us the code for `Event`?